# Algebraic property of infinitesimals $(m+dx=m)$

Tags: calculus, infinitesimals

If $m$ is real number and $dx$ is infinitesimal, then $m+dx=m$ (if $dx$ is infinitesimal and $dx^2$ is infinitesimal, then $dx+dx^2=dx$).

I suppose that $m+dx=m$, because if $\dfrac{m}{dx}=N$ ($N$-infinitely large quantity), then $m+dx=N\cdot dx+dx=m$. Is it true?

Thanks.

Comment: The "algebraic" approach to infinitesimals can lead to weird result... Basically $\lim_{dx \to 0} m+dx=m$.

Comment: Infinitesimals are not part of the real number system, so what is your definition of $\mathrm{d}x$? Usually, differentials are defined in terms of the differential $1$-forms or measures, and they do not easily blend with numbers or functions.

Comment: No. As soon as $m + dx = m$ in a group (or, moreover, a ring or an algebra), $dx=m-m=0$. So if you have infinitesimals different from $0$, $m + dx \neq m$.

Comment: Basically there are no infinitesmals in $\mathbb{R}$.